# What's the difference between "Bekenntnis" and "Geständnis"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

It seems both have the meaning of "confession". So what's the difference.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Bekenntnis

Man bekennt sich zu einer Überzeugung, einer (politischen) Gesinnung oder einem (religiösen) Glauben. In der christlichen Glaubenslehre gibt es daher auch eine Formel, die »*Glaubens**bekenntnis***« genannt wird, und die wichtigsten Punkte beinhaltet, an die ein Christ zu glauben hat.

Auch die öffentliche Äußerung eine bestimmte politische Partei zu unterstützen ist ein Bekenntnis, oder die Aussage davon überzeugt zu sein, dass »die da oben« uns mit Chemtrails vergiften wollen.

Ein Bekenntnis ist also eine Aussage, die man aus Überzeugung, und oft mit Stolz macht.

---

### Geständnis

Ein Geständnis ist eine Aussage, bei der man zugibt etwas moralisch verwerfliches oder etwas strafbares getan zu haben. Wenn also jemand ein Verbrechen begangen hat, und diese Tat später zugibt, dann legt er ein Geständnis ab.

Auch der Ehemann, der seiner Frau gesteht sie betrogen zu haben, legt ein Geständnis ab.

Ein Geständnis ist also eine Aussage, die man nicht gerne macht und lieber vermeiden würde.

Comment: Der betrügende Ehemann des Beispiels hat seiner Frau Jahre zuvor aber möglicherweise auch seine Liebe *gestanden* - es muss nicht immer strafbar sein.

Comment: @Hagen: aber zumindest unangenehm - was einiges an Rückschlüssen am Ausdruck "Liebe gestehen" zulässt :)